# OneDrive API (rest) . Folders and Files on Drives

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I try to make integration with OneDrive, using the API https://dev.onedrive.com/getting-started.htm

I make auth work and i can get list of drives in the account .
When i execute the API call /me/drives i am getting the list of drives fine.

But i can not find how to get list of folders on a drive, subfolders of a folder etc.

From the docs i can see there are some API for this, but it doesn't work for me.
https://dev.onedrive.com/items/list.htm

I have to execute on of.

```
GET /drive/items/{item-id}/children
GET /drive/root:/{item-path}:/children
```

But it doesn't work. I have a Drive ID from a list of drives. When i execute
GET /drive/items/DRIVEID/children
i have error "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

How to do this operation? should i use a drive ID or name? maybe the url is wrong, what must be the correct url if i have  a drive name, ID ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found how to do this. To understand i had to install some other tool where OneDrive API is used and debugged traffic with a https sniffer.

So, if endpoint is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
then paths are

```
/drives/DRIVEID/root/children
```

for root of drive

```
/drives/DRIVEID/root:myfolder/subfolder:/children
```

for a folder myfolder/subfolder

Final url is like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/DRIVEID/root:myfolder/subfolder:/children
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks. 
I had to modify the 'final url' you have here to make it work for me with with a / after /root: IE: /root:/myFolder:/children and then it gave me all the files under that folder.

Answer (score 0):

`/drive` is a shortcut for saying `/drives/<driveidofcaller>`. When you're attempting to query someone elses drive you'd want `/drives/DRIVEID`, and so extending to your example you'd want something like:

```
GET /drives/DRIVEID/root/children
```